# Order of execution of Servlet and Listener class in java

Tags: java, servlets

As part of my application development,  two things  I need to take care:

1. Read  the  configuration from properties file  load on startup using Servlet
2. Load on application  I need to start the listener to start the thread pool using specified pool size ,  which is getting from properties file

Note:  Listener is dependent  on servlet , in order to get some configured values.

Here my concern is , If both start  parallel ,  in that case it may be chance of  listener starts before  servlet , hence configured value not available that time.

How  to resolve it  .. ?

Comment: 1. LISTENER. 2. What kind of listener do You use? ServletContextListener, other?

Comment: 3. Hard to understand, specially sense "application". For most of us "application" is single project (sometimes WAR file) is servlet container, usually has logical connected servlet(s), listener and has stable rhythm of life.

Comment: Yes  , I'm using ServletContextListener  , While deploying my war file  , both servlet and listener starts parallel, due to this  I try to  access some values  which are  reading from configured properties file servlet , before that only listner starts .

Comment: Here my concern like  :  I f  any application having both listener  and servlet , both are  starting  as  part application launching , how to make  ordering , in order to resolve  dependency issues

Comment: order is always the same, is part of standard  (in same application)

Comment: you mean to say  , what  in order  i mentioned , it  will  execute  same way .